# How can I customize default to django REST serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault

I wants to read default value from `userprofile` automatically. Right now the offical method support `User` and `DateTime`. But I want my customized value. How can I do that?

```
owner = serializers.HiddenField(
    default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my workaround. Copy the example from source code and place it here.
Hope near future it has friendly solution.

```
class CurrentBranchDefault:
    def set_context(self, serializer_field):
        self.user = serializer_field.context['request'].user
        self.branch = self.user.userprofile.selected_branch

    def __call__(self):
        return self.branch

    def __repr__(self):
        return unicode_to_repr('%s()' % self.__class__.__name__)


class StaffOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    branch = serializers.HiddenField(default=CurrentBranchDefault())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate one hidden field, using other incoming fields in serializer, 
than you need to use serializer_field.context['request'].data

This "data" will be validated before "set_context()", so you can use it in safe.

I hope it will help someone else.

```
class DefineNoteType:
    def set_context(self, serializer_field):
        # setting field "type", calculated by other serializer fields
        data = serializer_field.context['request'].data
        subscriber = data.get('subscriber', None)
        connection = data.get('connection', None)
        if subscriber:
            self.type = 'subscriber_type'
        elif connection:
            self.type = 'connection_type'
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Custom error.')

    def __call__(self):
        return self.type


class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.HiddenField(default=DefineNoteType())
```